# Understanding Ajax call flow

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a bit confused in the call flow of Ajax, Could some one help me please?

My HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Content</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var xmlhttp;

function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc) {
    alert("4");
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    alert("5");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
    alert("6");
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction() {
    alert("1");
    loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt", function() {
        alert("2");
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("3");
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    });
}​
```

​

According to me the Alert box sequence should be

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

But it is

> 1456222223

Could some one please explain me why is the function being called 1'st. I was in the impression untill the parameter values are ready the function cannot be called.

Comment: Why would you think that `alert("4")` would happen later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, after firing the first alert, you're immediately invoking `loadXMLDoc`, and *passing* it the anonymous function (which contains the alerts "2" and "3". Note you're not executing this function; **just** passing a reference to it, so `loadXMLDoc` can execute it later.

So that explains why you see "1 4 5 6" first.

`xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;` sets the anonymous function we passed to `loadXMLDoc` as the [`onreadystatechange` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#Events). `onreadystatechange` is executed *multiple* times during an AJAX request; each time the browser determines the state of the request has changed (note that the `readyState` value for the AJAX request won't necessarily change each time this happens).

This explains why you see "2" being outputted multiple times.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    alert("3");
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Inside the `onreadystatechange` handler, you're checking whether the [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#Properties) is `4` and the `status` is 200. A `readyState` of 4 means the request has finished, and the check of whether `status == 200` checks the [HTTP response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

This is why you see "3" last; because it's only executed when the request completes (because of the conditions in the `if` statement).

For more information, you might want to see the [MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) on making AJAX Requests.

Comment: I understood the part where 222 is multiple times but why doesnt **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;** execute after step 5 ? why is it executing after step 6?

Comment: I am in the impression 1st **Function()** is evaluated then the Value is passed to **loadXMLDoc()**

Comment: @AdiMathur: because, like you did when you passed the function as a parameter to the `loadXMLDoc` function, you're setting the function as the `onreadystatechange` property of the `xmlhttp` variable; you're not *executing* it; the browser executes the function automatically *later* after you've initiated the request (`xmlhttp.send(null)`) and the state of the request starts changing.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it very nicely .
One last question - if I replace **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;** with **var b;
b=cfunc;**

then why isnt alert 2,3 comming up ? :(

Comment: Atlest in this 2 should execute ? if not 3 ?

Comment: Because the browser calls `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` when the state changes; if you don't assign your function to `onreadystatechange` (which you won't do if you do `var b; b = cfunc`), it won't get called!

Comment: Thank you :)

is there some Difference in **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;**
And **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc();**

Comment: @AdiMathur: The first assigns `cfunc` to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`. The second *executes* `cfunc`, and sets the result of the function to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` (which in this case will be `undefined`).

Comment: YA, but isnt** xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc; ** executing the function Cfunc ? thats the reason why alert 2 and 3 are comming up ? It isnt storing the **Variable Cfunc in xmlhttp.onreadystatechange **

Why is it so confusing ? :)

Comment: @AdiMathur: No, as I explained in my answer `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc` sets the `onreadystatechange` property to the `cfunc` property. You can call `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange()` if you want once you've set it to prove the point, and it'll alert `2`. As I've said already, the browser calls `onreadystatechange` internally as the AJAX request progresses, which is *why* "2" (and eventually "3") get shown. There's enough info provided by me and SLaks here to understand what goes on fully, it just might take a few reads... /o

Comment: Ill accept your Answer.. but still its not that clear.

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc(); is giving the alert is understandable but not xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc; ( which is also giving the output )

Answer (score 2):

`loadXMLDoc(...)` is a normal function call.
It executes immediately.

The callback that you pass it (containing `alert("2")`) is only executed when something calls it; namely, when the XMLHTTPRequest raises onreadystatechanged.

onreadystatechanged fires multiple times for different state changes, as you can see in the `readyState` property.

Comment: @Slaks- I understood the part where 222 is multiple times but why doesnt **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;** execute after step 5 ? why is it executing after step 6?

Comment: I am in the impression 1st **Function()** is evaluated then the Value is passed to **loadXMLDoc()**

Comment: @AdiMathur: The parameter is the function itself; it doesn't get called until later.

Comment: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc` just assigns a handler; it doesn't call anything.

Comment: if I replace **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;** with **var b; b=cfunc;** then why isnt alert 2,3 comming up ? :( 
Atlest in this 2 should execute ? if not 3 ?

Comment: @AdiMathur: _The function will only execute if you **call** it_.

Comment: Thank you :)

is there some Difference in **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;**
And **xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc();**

Comment: Yes.  `()` calls the function, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Slaks- YA, but isnt** xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc; ** executing the function Cfunc ? thats the reason why alert 2 and 3 are comming up ? It isnt storing the **Variable Cfunc in xmlhttp.onreadystatechange **

Why is it so confusing ? :)

Comment: It stores it, but it doesn't execute it.  It only gets executed when the XMLHTTPRequest calls the callback.